# How to rewrite only specific URLs?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

We have a CRM system written in PHP which is available via a private network. We decided to develope a REST API for our system, so we can create smartphone applications to enhance the software. This is how a simple URL looks:

```
servername.intra/index.php?module=Invoice&action=ListView
```

or

```
servername.intra/index.php?module=Store&action=SlipDetailViewIn&record=235894
```

I don't want to interfere with this old ugly but well-tried url structure, but I want to use well formed URIs for my RESTful API. So what I want is to use a rewrite rule only on URIs that  contain the ***/androidapi*** word after the domain.

I would like to make URIs for example like these:

```
servername.intra/androidapi
servername.intra/androidapi/production
servername.intra/androidapi/production/abc_123_2014
(and any other that has androidapi after the servername.intra/)
```

to redirect here:

```
servername.intra/androidapi/main.php?request=
servername.intra/androidapi/main.php?request=production
servername.intra/androidapi/main.php?request=production/abc_123_2014
```

I have tried this in .htaccess, but with no success:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/androidapi(.*)$ /androidapi/main.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It is important to keep any other URLs intact! Only have to rewrite the ones with the ***/androidapi*** in it!
I have never been a **mod_rewrite** or **regexp** magician, how could I solve this redirection problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `^`. It means starting of the string. In your case, `androidapi` may not be at the starting of the string.

Do this regex:

```
/androidapi(/?)(.*)
```

Full code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule /androidapi(/?)(.*) /androidapi/main.php?request=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's true, but it still does't redirect to `/androidapi/main.php?request=...` instead displays the index of androidapi folder.

Comment: Still the same effect. mod_rewrite surely works but somehow the URL doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: This solved the problem: 
`RewriteRule androidapi(/?)(.*)$ androidapi/main.php?request=$2 [QSA,L]`
And I modified the rewrite base to my working copy of the project: `RewriteBase /trunk/`